# Datagrid hover not working with alternate row colors - wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

This works just fine with DataGridRow..

```
   <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RolloverBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000" />
   </Trigger>
```

But when I add these, the mouse-over styles don't work..

```
<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightRowBrush0}" />
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightRowBrush1}" />
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of the styles matter.

Applying the alternation triggers before the others worked.

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightRowBrush0}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightRowBrush1}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RolloverBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: But This worked, `<Style TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
            <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="#FF282828"/>
        </Style>`